# How do I turn off mobile menu collapse for bootstrap 3 theme in drupal 8?

Tags: 8, navigation, bootstrap-theme

I am looking to use a different mobile menu solution and replace the default bootstrap 3 mobile menu.

How can I turn off the bootstrap collapsed mobile menu function?

Answer (score 1):

Just override the `menu--main.html.twig` template that comes along with the bootstrap theme, and replace the HTML classes with your own classes, then the bootstrap mobile styling won't affect your menu.